# Sping Data return List of null elements, but List has much elements

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

i have a problem

I have two entities:

Entity ALBERO

```
@Entity 
@IdClass(Albero.class)
@Table(schema="organo", name = "albero")
public class Albero implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "cmu")
    @OneToOne
private Struttura cmu;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "padre")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne 
    private Struttura padre;

    @Column(name = "div")
    private Date div;

@Column(name = "dfv")
private Date dfv;

    @Column(name = "cso", length=15)
    private String cso;

... get and set methods
```

and Entity STRUTTURA

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="organo", name="strutture")
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "Albero",
        classes =  @ConstructorResult(
                    targetClass = Albero.class,
                    columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name="cmu", type=String.class), 
                    @ColumnResult(name="padre", type=String.class)
                    }
        )       
)
public class Struttura implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "cmu")
    private String cmu; 

    @Column(name = "nome", length=512)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "tipologia")
    private String tipologia;

    @Column(name = "data_creazione")
    private Date data_creazione;

 ...get and set methods
```

I have a Repository AlberoRepository with the method:

```
public List<Albero> findByDfvIsNull();
```

and other method with native query:

```
String QUERY = "SELECT a.* FROM ALBERO a WHERE DFV IS NULL";
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = QUERY)
public List<Albero> findAllWithDfvIsNull();
```

La query on Oracle DB, give me a result with 802 record. 
**Each record are full; they have the values**.

Instead, the methods Java, give me a List of 802 object
**BUT THESE OBJECTS ARE NULL**.

Why ?
Can you help me ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem in `@IdClass` annotation.
You need a special class for PK:

```
public class AlberPK implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @JoinColumn(name = "cmu")
  @OneToOne
  private Struttura cmu;

  @Id
  @JoinColumn(name = "padre", nullable = true)
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  @ManyToOne
  private Struttura padre;
}
```

... and change a little in `Albero.class`:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(AlberPK.class)
@Table(schema = "organo", name = "albero")
public class Albero implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  private Struttura cmu;
  @Id
  private Struttura padre;

  ...
}
```

That have to work.

I am really don't understand - why you used complex PK? Re-mind your DB structure if possible. It will help you a lot in future.